# Flutter store Provider Value in variable to reuse it while listening

Tags: flutter, class, dart, provider

I am using the `Provider`-Package to store some data in my app. For that I also have a `Service-Class` where I define several functions. Now the thing is that I need these two values in almost every function:

```
  Year currentYear =
      Provider.of<CurrentlySelectedProvider>(context, listen: true)
          .currentYear;
  Month currentMonth =
      Provider.of<CurrentlySelectedProvider>(context, listen: true)
          .currentMonth;
```

Right now I am simply calling this inside every method of the class. But that seems a bit *stupid*. Is there a way to define those two values in my class somewhere so I can access them with a simple variable and I don't have to call the. whole thing over and over again?

I hope my problem is clear. Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a getter function:

```
CurrentlySelectedProvider get myProvider => Provider.of<CurrentlySelectedProvider>(context, listen: false);
```

You can then access it in each function like this:

```
myProvider.currentYear;
myProvider.currentMonth;
```

Comment: Gives the error "Undefined name 'context'."